# r Adding hyperlinks to bars in bar plots?

Tags: r, plot, hyperlink, plotly

Below is a simple example showing how to plot barplots using plotly library

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
  y = c(20, 14, 23),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar"
)
p
```

I am curious to find out if there is away to create hyperlinks on each of the bars in the barplot such that if user clicks on any of those bars, it opens a different barplot (any r plot) ?

Comment: Maybe just set links on the labels: `plot_ly( x = c("<a href=\"http://www.stackoverflow.com\">giraffes</a>", "orangutans", "monkeys"),y = c(20, 14, 23),name = "SF Zoo",  type = "bar")`?

Comment: @lukeA, that will work.